# CMAKE build task failing to find cmake command

Tags: azure-pipelines

I configured a CMAKE based build, via vsagent on windows, that was running great until very recently.  It started failing with the following error:

**Updated with debug output**

```
==============================================================================
Task         : CMake
Description  : Build with the CMake cross-platform build system
Version      : 1.0.25
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613719)
==============================================================================
agent.workFolder=C:\vsagent\_work
loading inputs and endpoints
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
loading INPUT_CMAKEARGS
loading INPUT_CWD
loaded 5
check path : C:\vsagent\_work\_tasks\CMake_7d831c3c-3c68-459a-a5c9-bde6e659596c\1.0.25\task.json
set resource file to: C:\vsagent\_work\_tasks\CMake_7d831c3c-3c68-459a-a5c9-bde6e659596c\1.0.25\task.json
system.culture=en-US
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Performance Tools/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Performance Tools\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.14393.0\x86/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.14393.0\x86\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\\MSBuild\15.0\bin/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319/cmake = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\vsagent\externals\git\cmd/cmake = C:\vsagent\externals\git\cmd\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\WINDOWS\system32/cmake = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\WINDOWS/cmake = C:\WINDOWS\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem/cmake = C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\/cmake = C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin/cmake = C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd/cmake = C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\/cmake = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\/cmake = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Program Files\dotnet\/cmake = C:\Program Files\dotnet\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\tools\go\bin/cmake = C:\tools\go\bin\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: c:\vsagent\scripts/cmake = c:\vsagent\scripts\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin"/cmake = C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin"\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps/cmake = C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\vsagent\bin/cmake = C:\vsagent\bin\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\vsagent\bin/cmake = C:\vsagent\bin\cmake
Absolute path for pathSegments: cmake = C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake
check path : C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake
cmake=C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake
cwd=C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\build
testing directory 'C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\build'
testing directory 'C:\vsagent\_work\1\s'
mkdir 'C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\build'
cmakeArgs=.. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\src\misc\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake arg: .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\src\misc\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
exec tool: C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake
Arguments:
..
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\src\misc\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-G
Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\src\misc\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake failed. spawn C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake ENOENT
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake failed. spawn C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake ENOENT
task result: Failed
CMake failed with error: C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake failed. spawn C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake ENOENT
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]CMake failed with error: C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake failed. spawn C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake ENOENT
Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]CMake failed with error: C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake failed. spawn C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\cmake ENOENT
rc:-4058
success:false
```

The problem is that it is trying to run:

```
rc:-4058
[command]C:\vsagent_work\6\s\cmake
```

The last build that worked was running a different command:

```
success:false
[command]c:\program files\cmake\bin\cmake.exe
```

Both builds were running vsagent version 2.114.0.  Both builds were running CMAKE Task version 1.0.25.  There were no build configuration changes between these two builds.  Perhaps an OS update was installed, but I can't find anything in the update history.

It turns out that before the build failures cmake was not in the system PATH.  It was in the user PATH of the user that installed vsagent.  I added the cmake directory to the system PATH after the failures started, but that did not make any difference.  The current PATH listed in the capabilities for the build agent is:

> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\tools\go\bin;c:\vsagent\scripts;"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin";C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\vsagent\bin

As a last data point, we do have a cmake directory at the root of our repo, so c:\vsagent_work\6\s\cmake is a directory on disk.

Does anyone have any idea what might have changed or any ideas on how to diagnose the issue?  Why isn't vsagent using cmake from the system PATH?

**Update: I've reinstalled the agent and it is now at version 2.120.1**

Comment: Try to setup a new build agent on this machine, then queue build with this agent and check the result.

Comment: Queue a build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the build logs for cmake step here. And can you also check the capabilities settings of the build agent?

Comment: I've updated the question with debug output.  I also upgraded the agent and still repro the problem.  What would you like me to check in the capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the quotes around

> "c:\program files\cmake\bin"

in the PATH variable that causes the problem.  path.resolve() turns this in to

> C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin"

when

> C:\vsagent\_work\1\s

is the current working directory.  Removing the quotes fixes the issue.

There is also a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/d487d3a0eb602c207bb4c0cf77064ed7df51fbac/node/lib/task.ts#L656 .  The call to

> stats(tool).isFile

should end in '()' since isFile is a function.  Because there is a 'cmake' directory in the current working directory, the lack of parens causes the if statement to resolve to true.